# PHP/HTML Script runs twice

Tags: php, html, duplicates, execute

Here is my beginning and end code snippet.

```
<?php
    error_log('Program Overview Start');
    include_once '../../includes/SessionStart.php'; 
    .....
    error_log('Program Overview Done');
    exit();
?>
```

it is called like this (from a menu script):

```
<tr>
<td><a href="ProgramOverview/" class="smartButton">Program Overview</a></td>
</tr>
```

My php_error.log shows:

```
[25-Aug-2017 12:31:11 America/Los_Angeles] Program Overview Start
[25-Aug-2017 12:31:20 America/Los_Angeles] Program Overview Done
[25-Aug-2017 12:31:21 America/Los_Angeles] Program Overview Start
[25-Aug-2017 12:31:30 America/Los_Angeles] Program Overview Done
```

The content of the page shows only once. All the data is correct.

All the research I've done says the "typical" reason for a page running more than once is HTML related and that if the php_error.log only shows one entry then the problem is definitely HTML.

I have no POST or GET in the script that runs twice.

The only javascript I have is:

```
    <head>
    <?php 
        require_once('../../includes/Head.php'); 
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function openNewTab(state,year){
                window.open('/reports/ProgramOverviewByState/?
state='+state+'&poltype=all&exclude_ownop=n&exclude_fleet=n&year='+year);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
```

Which is executed by a click on a data row:

```
<tr onclick="openNewTab('<?php echo $old_state; ?>','<?php echo $selected_year; ?>');">
```

Why is this double execute happening to me?

TIA for any hints or help you may provide.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser to see which pages are requested by the browser. Is it double there as well? It is most likely that you're calling the same page by using an html anchor as well as javascript.

Comment: After checking the developers tools in the browser as @KIKOSoftware suggested, try for a second to remove the session start line or include. Some similar problems showed with users for starting session in later lines after some echos.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The developer tools show that the script was called once.

Comment: @Anddo if I remove the session start line (include) the script will not run. There are absolutely no echo statements prior to the session start include, nor are there any in the include.

Comment: @EdK But it loads once or twice then ? Also, try to put something like `console.log('Any Text');` out side the function to work on loading the page and see if it load twice. One the other hand, the developer tools showing the loading twice maybe means the developer actually required the page twice.